# Minimizing a linear objective plus $\| \cdot \|_1$

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, regularization

What is the best method for solving the following convex regularization problem?

$$ \text{minimize} ~~ c^T x  + \| A x \|_{1} \quad \text{subject to} \quad -1 \leq x_i \leq 1 $$

where $c$ is a vector and $A$ is a matrix.

The original problem is a non-convex problem, but when I apply my algorithm the subproblems of my algorithm come out convex in the form of above. So I am trying to solve the above subproblem by convex optimization techniques.

Comment: You could solve the dual, which I think is $\min_{\| \lambda \|_\infty \le 1} \|A \lambda +c \|_1$. If you are looking for numerical solutions, you could look at http://cvxr.com/cvx/.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you. The links is helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be made into a linear programming problem using some auxiliary variables:

minimize $c^T x + \sum_j t_j$ subject to
$-1 \le x_i \le 1$ for each $i$, $(Ax)_j \le t_j$ and $-(Ax)_j \le t_j$ for each $j$.

Comment: good idea.  I assume it can't be solved in a better way